# adobe air ios7 notification center behaviour in FS app and non FS apps

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, actionscript, air

When in fullscreen app, when you pull finger from above, the notification center icon pops out, and than you have to pull it again to open notification center, but in non fullscreen apps, notification center pops out immediately.

Is it possible to alter the behaviour in non fullscreen apps to behave the same as in full screen apps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Go to any fullscreen application (Adobe AIR or not) in iOS and try to access notification center. It behaves the same way, and it always has. This is just the default behavior of notification center in fullscreen apps in iOS.